# How Do I Make a Background Pixel Video Show Up In My Header Section With Text On Top Of It

Tags: html, css, codepen

I'm currently working on a project using HTML and CSS and want to display a background video from Pexel that takes up the whole top portion of the screen above where the "hello" and "meet the team" sections are (not including the navbar). I have linked my Codepen below but here are the specific areas I believe my errors would be.

HTML:

```
 <div class="all">

  <head id="home">
    <div id="welcome-section">
      <!-- The video -->
<!-- The video -->
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="pexels-magda-ehlers-5306154.mp4&" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
      html, .all {
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      background-image: url("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41g8yeF0NWL._AC_.jpg");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size:cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
    }


#welcome-section{
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:50px;
  color:white;
  height:100vh;
  
}

/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I've used the information within these links but the video still won't show up. Any help would be appreciated!

Codepen:https://codepen.io/coder3o2-4/pen/ExXYeRY

Links I followed and implemented:

https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, even though I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve.

The problem in the codepen is that you linked a video file that is not there, where did you save your mp4 video? The src attribute of the video tag should be the path to the video file on your local/production server, such as /assets/video/myvideo.mp4. If you're not sure if the video is correctly linked or not, simply inspect your page with chrome, right click on the video URL and click the "open in a new tab" key. If you can see the video working it means it's correctly linked.

Other than that you'll might have to remove the background from the first section and play with the z-index property for the video itself, in order to correctly position it "below" the rest of the content on the z axis.

See in the image I'm attaching, I linked a random video to see if it worked (the grass you see).

[image]

Comment: Okay so I've downloaded a pexel video and right now it's in my documents folder(i'm on a mac). So to embed the video, would I do <video src = "/downloads/pexels-magda-ehlers-5306154.mp4"></video>. This still won't make the video show up for me.

Comment: If you're working locally you probably need to skip the first /, so the src should be downloads/pexels-magda-ehlers-5306154.mp4. It might also depend a lot on where your root is (i.e. with laravel the root is the public folder).

The / in front will work while deployed online though.

If you're in doubt, try to set this as src: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4